# TFS overlay branch mappings

Tags: tfs

Can Microsoft's Team Foundation overlay multiple branches to a single source branch?

I'm trying to map 3 locations from the depot to 1 location in my workspace, like below:

```
//workspace/Project/Source/...  //depot/Project/Source/...   
+//workspace/Project/Source/...  //depot/branch1/Source/...
+//workspace/Project/Source/...  //depot/branch2/Source/...
```

There is a single source directory and im trying to overlay two branches one with fixes another with pending changes.

The version is TFS 2017

Comment: In what context? A build? And what version of TFS? This question is tagged with 3 different versions.

Comment: Context is mapping several branches with one fixed file on top of the main source code. The version is TFS2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workspace does not allow the same TFS folder to be mapped to more than one local directory. We could also not map multiple server branches to the same local folder/location which already be mapped.

If you do this it will not overlay the files, instead it will pop up the error message something like below screenshot:

[image]

You have to either merge changes in the server first and than get latest version for your local files or keep local folder with the different subfolders(the same structure) as server side.